# Sun Java keytool importing EV certificates into a single keystore

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, sun, tomcat

At my current job we are using tomcat, customers have custom web portals setup on their own local machines. EV certs are new to me, they have 2 part intermediary and a primary certificate. For our product to work it appears I need to get all three parts installed under a single keystore entry. How can I roll all three parts into a single x.509 compliant file for import?

They syntax I am using is as follows:

/blah/system/j2sdk/bin/keytool -import -alias foo -keystore /zix/system/jdk1.5.0_06/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file certname.pem -trustcacerts

where foo = the keystore name and certname.pem is the main cert.

I have tried importing the intermediate certs under their own names into the keystore and I don't know if it's just the product I have to work with (not vanilla tomcat) or what but it doesn't see those. I have seen a working system and all three certs were under the single keystore alias. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the way to do this is to put all the files in a single text file with a .pem extension you can then import them into a keystore under a single keystore name.